# Clang++ 6.0 Memory Sanitizer not reporting uninitialised local variable in a function whose return value dictates a conditional branch

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, clang++

The following code(in `src.cpp`) was used to experiment with Clang's Memory Sanitizer (MSan)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int add(int x, int y) {
    int sum;
    sum = x + y;
    return sum;
}
int main() {
    if(add(10, 20) > 0) {
        std::cout << "Greater";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

We can clearly see that `sum` is unitialized and would cause an undenfined behaviour. As per [MSan Github Wiki](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/MemorySanitizer)

> MemorySanitizer is bit-exact: it can track uninitialized bits in a
>   bitfield. It will tolerate copying of uninitialized memory, and also
>   simple logic and arithmetic operations with it. In general,
>   MemorySanitizer silently tracks the spread of uninitialized data in
>   memory, and reports a warning when a code branch is taken (or not
>   taken) depending on an uninitialized value.

This clearly seems to conform to this use case since the `if` branch will be taken based on the intial value of `sum`. However, no error/warning is displayed while running this code compiled with

`clang++  -fsanitize=memory -fsanitize-memory-track-origins -O0 -std=c++14 src.cpp -o src`

Clang 6.0 is used on Linux x86_64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*sum* is not uninitialized, because the next instruction is the assignment of the sum variable. 
This code is the same as:

`int sum = x + y;`

And thats why it is initialized.

Comment: Oops ! I completely overlooked that, my bad.